# Liftings of Nullhomotopic Maps

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is the lifting of a nullhomotopic map always a loop in a path connected space?
This question is perhaps very trivial,but I am struggling with it.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming you meant to ask about maps of the circle which are null homotopic, and you can find a proof in any textbook covering covering theory, say, Massey or Hatcher.

Comment: I have got.Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

No.  If you lift the map from $I$ to $S^1$, that goes around the circle once, to the covering of $S^1$ by $\mathbb{R}$, then the image will be the straight line path from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Your example is not null homotopic.

Comment: @studiosus Yes it is.  All maps from a contractible space are null homotopic.  I am not demanding the map fix the endpoints.  There is nothing about that in the question.